# Background filter without changing child divs

Tags: html, css

I want to use a filter for my background, but the content within this div should not be affected by this filter.

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ruodq59d/)

Code:

```
#start{
    background: url('http://placekitten.com/700/1000') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height:1000px;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
}

#startbox{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 13, 0.4);
    margin-right: 250px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    height: 350px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 30px;
    -webkit-filter:none;
    filter: none;

    }
```

DUMMY HTML:

```
<div id="start">
    <div id="startbox">Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way as wth opacity, you can't stop inheritance of the filter from parent to child. The only thing you can do is put the background on a child element, not parent. For example you could use a :before pseudo element on #start

```
    #start {position:relative}
    #start:before {
       background:url(.....) no-repeat 0 0; 
       content:''; 
       width:100%; 
       height:100%; 
       filter:blur;
       position:absolute;
       left:0;
       top:0;
       z-index:-1
    }
    #startbox {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 13, 0.4);
        margin-right: 250px;
        margin-left: 250px;
        height: 350px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 30px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how flexible you are with adding elements, but just a quick something:

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id="start"></div>
    <div id="startbox">Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}

#start{
    background: url('http://placekitten.com/700/1000') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height:1000px;

}

#start {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
}

#startbox{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 20%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 13, 0.4);
    margin-right: 250px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    height: 350px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    }
```

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvjwLg0v/)